# electron アプリを selenium から操作すると、クリック動作しない場合があります

Tags: electron, selenium-webdriver

**概要**

・electron アプリを selenium から操作しようとしたのですが、クリック操作が動作しない・指定とは別の場所がクリック操作される等の場合があります。
・electron アプリを自分で操作した場合には問題なく動作しています。

何が起きているのか分かる方はいますか？

**環境**
・MacBook Pro / OS X Yosemite (10.10.4)
・Electron
　・v0.33.1
　・v0.36.1
・ChromeDriver
　・chromedriver-v2.15-darwin-x64
　・chromedriver_mac32_2_20
・jQuery
　・1.11.3

**詳細**

まず、以下の内容の HTML を Electron アプリにしました。

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script>
window.jQuery = window.$ = require("jquery");

$(function() {
  $("#link1").click(function() {
    $("#status1").text("OK");
  });

  $("#link2").click(function() {
    $("#status2").text("OK");
  });

  $("#link3").click(function() {
    $("#status3").text("OK");
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span id="status1"></span><a href="#1" id="link1" class="link">link1</a><br>
<span id="status2"></span><a href="#2" id="link2" class="link">link2</a><br>
<span id="status3"></span><a href="#3" id="link3" class="link">link3</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

アプリを起動し、各リンクを押下するとリンクの前に「OK」が表示され、想定通り動いていることを確認しました。

次に、Selenium で以下の ruby コード(抜粋)を書きました。

```
...
link1 = driver.find_element(:id, 'link1')
link1.click

sleep(5)

link2 = driver.find_element(:id, 'link2')
link2.click

sleep(5)

link3 = driver.find_element(:id, 'link3')
link3.click
...
```

これを実行すると link1, link2 は問題ないのですが、link3 のみ「OK」が表示されません。

何が起きているのか分かる方はいますか？

html, コードに同様の link4 を追加して実行すると、selenium 側の link3.click 操作時に、アプリ側の link4 のイベントが発生しています。（？？？）

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/seleniumjp/j4VBsXFPApQ

Answer (score 1):

これは、私の環境では同じ事象を起こすことができず、Electronでも想定通りの動作をさせることしかできませんでした。
ElectronやWebDriver以外のところ、例えば次のような部分を追ってみると良いかもしれません。

- WebDriver側のchromeOption.binaryの指定が古いビルドのElectronアプリであるなど、テストとテスト対象が合致していない
- Node.jsのバージョンが古い
- developer consoleが表示されていて処理コンテキストが変わってしまっている

---

- MacBook Pro / OS X Yosemite (10.10.5)
- jQuery

  - 1.11.3
- Node.js

  - 5.3.0
- Selenium

  - 2.48.2

ElectronとChromeDriverは次の組み合わせの両方とも動きました。

- Electron 0.33.1 + ChromeDriver 2.15
- Electron 0.36.1 + ChromeDriver 2.20

Comment: hiroshitoda 様

ありがとうございます！
まだ私の方では、動作させられていないのですが、想定通りの動作をさせられるということで、希望が見えました。

お手数をおかけして申し訳ないのですが、正常動作した各種ツールのバージョンも教えていただけないでしょうか。

Electron / Node.js / WebDriver等

よろしくお願いします。